# I can rotate an object around y axis in iOS using swift, but how to rotate many objects around a single axis?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created this function which rotates an object (imageViewLogo) around the Y Axis

the question is, how to rotate many objects around a specific point ?

[image]

for example the squares rotate around the blue axis.

```
func animate()
{
    var id = CATransform3DIdentity
    id.m34 =  -1.0 / 1000

    var transformAnim            = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath:"transform")
    transformAnim.values         = [
        NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DRotate(id, 0 * CGFloat(-M_PI_2), 0, 1.0, 0)),
        NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DRotate(id, 1 * CGFloat(-M_PI_2), 0, 1.0, 0)),
        NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DRotate(id, 0 * CGFloat(-M_PI_2), 0, 1.0, 0))
    ]
    transformAnim.keyTimes       = [0, 0.5, 1.0]
    transformAnim.duration       = 0.7

    self.imageViewLogo.layoutIfNeeded()

    self.imageViewLogo.layer.addAnimation(transformAnim, forKey: "transform")
}
```

Comment: @DeBanana, no. In iOS all UI code needs to be run on the main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing to do will be to put all your views that you want to rotate inside another view, and then rotate that superview. (You can also do the same thing with placing multiple layers inside another layer and rotating the containing layer, but that's more work.)

Comment: thanks man, that is a simple solution, tell me how to make this not (2 sided), so i mark this as best answer, when i rotate something i don't want the other side to appear.

Comment: Er, you can't. If you rotate something around the Y axis, when your rotation gets to 90/-90 degrees, the bottom is exposed. You say you don't want the other side to appear. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: if you worked on some 3D Packages like 3D Max, there is an option called [force 2 sided], this make a quad (for example) appear from both sides, and when [force 2 sided] is off it wont appear from the other side, currently what is like [force two sided] feature is on, i want it off.

Comment: To repeat my question, what do you want to show on the screen when you rotate more than 90 degrees? What should you see on the backs of those views?

Comment: on top of that emptiness, i wanted to show a textfield and 2 buttons.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question.

Comment: Thanks
"What should you see on the backs of those views?"
ok, i want to show this on back of those view : , a textfield and 2 buttons, i can't explain further.

Comment: if you need an illustrating 3d rendered video i can create a one and post it to you here so you know 100% what i mean.

Comment: I can't promise you I'll be able to help you, or that I will have time to do so, but if you want help getting a specific effect then you're going to have to describe it.

Comment: i accepted your answer here, and asked another one here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240951/how-to-make-objects-appear-from-one-side-when-i-rotate-them-in-ios-code-gif
that has this sub question.

Comment: Don't ask a second, identical question. Since you've done that, please close this question.